# Making the bot send pings in <@blabla> format

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I am trying to make the bot send normal @pings in <@123> pattern so it doesnt ping but u can still see if it tried to ping or not

```js
if (message.content.includes('@')) {
    if (message.author.bot) {
        const channel = client.channels.cache.get('1204760182567993354') //PING BLOCKER MHC
        channel.send("`" + message.content + "`")
    }
}
```

This works but it does so on the entire message, How could i make it only act on the ping, where it would show like

Hello `@ping`

instead of

`Hello @ping`

Soz very new to Javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do this you can use a [regular expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_expressions):

```js
const message = "Hello @ping"

if (message.includes('@')) {
  const contentWithBackticks = message.replace(/@(\S+)/g, '`@$1`');
  console.log(contentWithBackticks); // "Hello `@ping`"
}
```

So this will detect the `@` and add the backticks